GIT installation ERROR "Internal error: Failed to expand shell folder constant "commondesktop" on Windows
I am trying to install GIT on Windows 11, but I am encountering an error message that states:
"Runtime error (at 27:202):
Internal error: Failed to expand shell folder constant •commondesktop•."
I have tried restarting the installation process multiple times and even rebooted my computer, but the issue persists. The error appears to be related to the installer attempting to access a specific system folder or directory that it cannot locate or expand properly. Has anyone else experienced this issue while trying to install GIT on a Windows 11 system, and if so, what steps did you take to resolve it? Is there a specific configuration or setting that needs to be adjusted to allow the installation to proceed without encountering this runtime error? Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!
addition
I have now tried to create a new user and the installation was successful. I do not know where the problem lies with the admin user

Do you have a c:\Users\Public\Desktop\ (or whatever disk name?)

yes i have c:\Users\Public\Desktop (Do you mean the name of the user?)

You can create a formal Answer to your Question, and fill it in with the details that you do have in your addition.
